# html : iframe not showing content in html

Tags: html, iframe, xhtml

I want to show a youtube video in html 4. For that, I am using iframe. But the content of iframe is not showing.

```
<iframe frameborder="1" width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8kSrkz8Hz8"></iframe>
```

FYI: I am using Firefox 29.0 and Chrome 35.0. Both browsers are showing the same result.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change your src with `//www.youtube.com/embed/C8kSrkz8Hz8`

your code shoud look like this

```
<iframe frameborder="1" width="420" height="345" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/C8kSrkz8Hz8"></iframe>
```

Find code under each video on youtoube at Share menu.

Answer (score 10):

When you try to put the whole YouTube page into an iframe, it sends a HTTP header called `X-Frame-Options` with the `SAMEORIGIN` value, which tells the browser, that the page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

You should use the provided embed code (you can find it below every YouTube video), which is also an iframe, but with a different URL. It will only show the player.

In this case, the embed code would be:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/C8kSrkz8Hz8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: if im allowing the user to load random websites in an `iframe` in my electron app, is there a way to work around websites that send the `X-Frame-Options` header, so the website in the `iframe` will always be displayed??

Answer (score 1):

replace you Iframe with this one. this works for you.

```
<iframe width="640" height="390" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/C8kSrkz8Hz8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

missing `attributes` are: `frameborder="0"`,  `allowfullscreen`

Answer (score 1):

You should change the youtube URL to remove the "s" so it looks like this:

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/C8kSrkz8Hz8" frameborder="1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You should also be able to embed a youtube video from the page. Please see the screenshot attached:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I tried it this way and worked for me. Changing your src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C8kSrkz8Hz8"
following the other parameters.

Comment: Please try to post a complete answer.